# component manager gives the error that cron jobs has not been configured yet

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab

I reindexed the indexers running the following commands:

```
php ./magento cron:run                    
php ./magento indexer:reindex
```

and the reindex was performed succesfully

Bt when I open component manager in magento admin, it checks for readiness and gives the following error

[image]

My server's OS is windows 7. So, please give the relevant answer.

Comment: Please check your PHP version also.

Comment: PHP version is 5.6.23 . which is required version? it does not give any information related to the required version.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at this post too, [CronjobError](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158686/error-from-updater-application-cron-script-cron-job-has-not-been-configured-yet/162469)

it solved the same problem while installing magento 2 extension