# Error from Updater Application Cron Script: Cron job has not been configured yet

Tags: magento2, error, cron, crontab

Within the Magento web component wizard, when we try to install extensions, we receive the following error during the Readiness Check:

```
Check Cron Scripts
Cron script readiness check failed. Hide detail

Error from Updater Application Cron Script:
Cron job has not been configured yet

For additional assistance, see cron scripts help.
```

We've configured and setup the cron tasks according to the magento documentation, with our resulting cron file looking like this:
[image: cron]

From the CLI, we are able to run the cron successfully with `magento cron:run` so, am I missing something here? Obviously, the cron jobs have been configured, and have been ran, so are there any other potential causes for the readiness check failing with this error?

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/cron.html

Comment: We've already gone through and configured according to those docs and haven't been able to find anything that fixes the issue.

Comment: Instead of `/usr/bin/php` please write only `php` Example `* * * * * php /var/www/html/.....` for all & check

Comment: @AnkitShah You the man! That seemed to do the trick. Any idea why in the magento docs they state "<path to php binary> is the absolute file system path to your PHP binary" as it seems to be working with the relative path but not the absolute?

Comment: On our server when we run `which php` it gives same path `/usr/bin/php`, But to run cron u need to only use `php` thats it

Comment: Hmm, gotcha. Thanks for the tip, everything is working as it should now. If you want to post your suggestion as an answer, I'll mark it as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `/usr/bin/php`, please use only `php`

**Example**

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/.....
```

Implement for all & check. It should work :)

Answer (score 4):

Apparently theres a problem with a generated file somewhere
I went into {magento-directory}/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Controller/Environment.php

around Line 194

i commented out :

```
 //$setupCheck = $this->cronScriptReadinessCheck->checkSetup();
 //$updaterCheck = $this->cronScriptReadinessCheck->checkUpdater();
```

and replaced it with :

```
$setupCheck = ['success' => 1];
$updaterCheck = ['success' => 1];
```

this just skips the Cron check altogether.

Comment: It doesn't feel right to do that. But heck, I did it anyways. It keeps bothering me with that error message. I know cron works because it was working a moment but other error showed. So I cleared cache and stuff under var/.update_cron_status and cron error kept popping.